# Can I replace zapier with something else that creates a webhook to catch a hook

Tags: rest, webhooks, zapier

I'm using a 3rd party software and the only way to get data out is by using a webhook.  I have created the webhook using zapier and after retrieving the data, zapier creates a new spreadsheet row.  After which my developers get that data and using an api send into my software.  Wondering if it's possible to eliminate zapier alltogether (very expensive when doing 100's of thousands of task per month).  Essentially would like to go from

> 3rd Party Software -> Webhook (using zapier) -> Google Sheet (using
>   Zapier) -> My software (using API)

**To**

> 3rd Party Software -> Webhook (using zapier alternative) -> My
>   software (using API)

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success using Google Cloud Functions (or AWS Lambdas). Any serverless product lends well to this. Here is why I use Google Cloud Functions:

1. A function can be triggered with an HTTP call (ie A webhook POST)
2. It can scale up or down based on demand
3. You get 2 million calls per month free (view their pricing calculator to see usage pricing as well)
4. Your code has 9 minutes to execute

There are more things I like about it vs AWS, but it really comes down to personal preference.

Check out more [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)

Answer (score 0):

The best alternatives as mentioned above are probably Google Cloud functions / AWS Lamda (if you are technically minded) or if you are less technical then you could try a cheaper Zapier alternative like N8N or make.io.